# Is there a way to aggregate more than one Microsoft Project files into one?

Tags: .net, office-addins, ms-project, ms-project-server-2013, ms-project-server-2016

A large PMO group includes 10 distinct PM's -- each PM creates and maintains a MS Project file for their respective group. We are looking into rolling up the project files into one aggregated project file on recurring basis for executive reporting and management purposes. We can assume all project files follow a set template.

Has anyone had experience with a similar problem? Are there any pre-existing tools that I can leverage to achieve roll-up / integration of projects in a continuous and/or automatic way?

My first hunch was to write something custom -- but before going there, I'd like to know from experts if there is a better approach I should be taking.

If not, do you have any recommendation on what technology is most feasible to write a custom tool in?

Comment: can you add a little more info about the problem(s) you're trying to solve? Aggregating project files is a proposed solution to what? Also, are the multiple project files owned & maintained by you or by others? Do you need a common resource pool in the aggregated project (like for leveling)? Or, is your intent to just pull in milestone data?

Comment: Thanks Jerred for the questions. I have updated the question to include background context. The end goal is to manage and report at an aggregated executive level.

"A large PMO group includes 10 distinct PM's -- each PM creates and maintains a MS Project file for their respective group. We are looking into rolling up the project files into one aggregated project file on recurring basis for executive reporting and executive purposes. We can assume all project files follow a specific template."

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way to do this is to setup a master project that contains each of the PM's projects as a subproject. Each PM would still manage their own schedule and all schedules can be viewed together in the master project.

This is also how links can be created between schedules if there are dependencies between the PM's areas.

[Here's more info.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Plans-within-plans-master-projects-and-subprojects-e9c8ae07-8f21-4cc4-aedb-101fa6341a70)

Comment: Thank you! How would version control be managed? My concern is that if sub-projects are being managed independently, we may run into versioning conflicts.

Comment: Each PM would manager their own file. If all files can be stored in the same folder, there is only one copy of each file, thus no versioning required. If PMs each have their own folders, then they would post a copy of their working file to a common folder (where the master project is) on a regular basis for reporting (e.g. weekly or monthly).